# Redirecting a user but not Googlebot to solve problem with iFrames in content

Tags: redirects, googlebot, javascript

**TLDR**

To work around a problem with a third party [documentation writing software](http://www.innovasys.com/product/dx/overview) I need to redirect a page to another page **but only if a user in browser is looking at it**. I want the google bot to see the original page but the user to see the redirected page.

The webpages are hosted as raw HTML/css/javascript on a server with no .htaccess. I can only use Javascript to do the redirect.

I have good legitimate, non-spammy reasons to do so. Any solutions welcome!

---

**The longer detail**

Documentation writing software that I am using outputs pages that look like this:

[image]

It is structured (by the Documentation software) to be a Treeview with table of contents on the left, then an iFrame on the right hosting the actual content.

**As a result, google bot cannot see or crawl the actual content from the iFrame version**. Instead it crawls the inner page hosted in the iframe, which is here:

[image]

That would be fine but now when a user clicks on a link in google:

[image]

... they are taken to the page above (no iFrame, no nice tree view) so are unaware any other documentation exists.

To workaround this I've put a short in place which displays a button at the top of the page prompting the user to redirect to the iFrame version.

[image]

I'd much rather have an auto redirect though, which would give a better user experience, but I need to preserve Google seeing the original page to ensure that the site gets indexed.

Answer (score 2):

This is high risk practice.
IMHO... You will sooner or later probably get banned in google because of sneaky redirects. Are you sure you want to try it anyway?

```
if (!(/bot|googlebot/i.test(navigator.userAgent))) {
    document.location.href="UrlToBeRedirectedIfNotGoogleBot";
}
```

JavaScript code above relies on `navigator.userAgent` variable.
We are preparing regular expression with words "bot" and "googlebot", that is case insensitive (`/i` modifier thou). Then we are testing `navigator.userAgent` variable if it matches. Exclamation mark negates this result, so code in curly braces is being executed only if userAgent does not match regular expression.

`document.location.href="...";` is one of standard methods of redirecting in JavaScript. There might be another way of doing it which would better suit your needs.

Comment: This is what my SEO expert told me and I don't want to get banned or risk an SEO penalty./ I'm wondering about another solution: to have a 'Remember this choice' option on the popup for user to redirect, and use cookies to remember it? Thoughts?